# Launch keyboard event from React ref

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-events, react-ref

I have a React component that has an `input` element with an attached [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I am aware of the common: `inputRef.current.focus();` usage of a ref to focus a text input. But, I am struggling to find a good solution to dispatch a certain keyboard event from `inputRef.current`. I have tried:

```
let downEv = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 40, 'which': 40});
inputRef.current.dispatchEvent(downEv);
```

But, that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyboardEvent is a native browser event (which is different than React's Synthetic event) hence you need to add a native listener as well like below in order to listen to them. example on [csb](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-firefly-bhupg)

```
useEffect(()=>{
    ref.current.addEventListener('keydown',handleKeyDown)
  },[ref])
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this, and not need to use ref.

You can try isolating what you want to trigger by doing this:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    // Whatever you want to trigger
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

```
<input onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
```

You can also trigger this from a form if you prefer:

```
<form onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: I understand how to capture a keyboard event. I am trying dispatch a keyboard event not capture it.

Comment: Got it.  What's the need to dispatch a keyboard event synthetically?  My understanding is that keyboard events can only be triggered by a keyboard.  The logic or action you want to happen when that keyboard event happens can be created independently and triggered by any other piece of code.   There may be something if you dig through SyntheticEvents in React's docs.  https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events